# How to avoid repeating row values in field hierarchy when joining over an ID

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, tableau-api, window-functions

I am trying to figure out a way to make rows of top level of hierarchy appear only once in SQL, directly or via an extra column:

[image]

Quantity 1 is from Table 1, Quantity 2 is from Table 2, and they are joined over the ID field. Q1 and Q2 have nothing to do with one another mathematically speaking. I would like to have the following column as a result, because I will be summing Q1 and visualizing it in parallel with the individual values of Q2.

[image]

Is there any way to do this with SQL? Or in Tableau if anyone knows a solution, as I will be plotting the data in Tableau.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` - but you need a column that defines the order of records (something that is unique across the whole table, or at least across records that have the same `id`). I assumed that you have such column and that it is called `ordering_id`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) = 1
        then quantity1
    end quantity1_edit
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

For Tableau only you could take the MIN or MAX per ID and sum that. Depending on your viz and what you want to do it could be a simple MIN does the job. Maybe you need to sum the results, so could do a

```
WINDOW_SUM(MIN([Qty1]))
```

Another option is a FIXED function:

```
{FIXED [ID]: MIN([Qty1])}
```

You can sum that. Performance may be affected with very large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau has a feature called data blending that is a good fit in situations like this. With data blending, you are making parallel independent queries to two different data sources (one of which is distinguished to be the primary data source) Then the (aggregated) query results from each data source are combined on the client side in a way that is similar  to a client-side left-join of the aggregated results (where the primary source is on the left)

So if your data rows do not have a meaningful relationship, just that two tables can be summarized grouping by similar fields, then see if data blending will work for your case. See the Tableau help for details. Some of the edge cases in data blending can get a bit arcane, but the basic straightforward cases work out quite well.